# How to trace out overlapping DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four `div`s which are animated using size, height and positions; that means, these `div`s change their height, width, left and top.

***FOCUS:***
**I want to stop that animation when any of these two `div`s become overlapped.**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container_1">
  <div id="anim_1"></div>
  <div id="anim_2"></div>
</div>

<div id="container_2">
  <div id="anim_3"></div>
  <div id="anim_3"></div>
</div>
```

If any two `anim` `div`s of any container (i.e. container_1 OR container_2) bocome overlapped then I have to stop the animation of both two `container` `div`s.

Now, how can I trace out this overlapping using JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT?

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently Detect When Sibling Elements Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560926/efficiently-detect-when-sibling-elements-overlap)

Comment: @drachenstern your link is not my desired solution. So this question is not a duplication. The scenario is different from your given link.

Comment: Then feel free to describe how this is not different from that. Remarkably enough, giving code that _demonstrates_ the problem and gives us some insight allows us to make _better decisions_ than when we have to guess.

Comment: @drachenstern here I give some code snippet. Now help me.

Comment: this is almost an exact duplicate of that question. You just need to account for the fact that you're going to be testing for two sets of collisions, not just one.

Comment: @drachenstern Now it make me clear. As I'm new to jquery or javascript so I'm not so quick adopter. Thanks for your kind help.So morgar and you both give me the solution.But morgar gives it as answer. So I have to receive it.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the answer in this other question:

[Efficiently Detect When Sibling Elements Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560926/efficiently-detect-when-sibling-elements-overlap)