# How to detect if a certain range resides (partly) within an other range?

Tags: algorithm, math, comparison, tree

Lets say I've got two squares and I know their positions, a red and blue square:

```
redTopX;
redTopY;
redBotX;
redBotY;
blueTopX;
blueTopY;
blueBotX;
blueBotY;
```

Now, I want to check if square blue resides (partly) within (or around) square red. This can happen in a lot of situations, as you can see in this image I created to illustrate my situation better:
[alt text http://www.feedpostal.com/etc/ranges.gif](http://www.feedpostal.com/etc/ranges.gif)

Note that there's always only one blue and one red square, I just added multiple so I didn't have to redraw 18 times.

My original logic was simple, I'd check all corners of square blue and see if any of them are inside square red:

```
if (
((redTopX >= blueTopX) && (redTopY >= blueTopY) && (redTopX <= blueBotX) && (redTopY <= blueBotY)) || //top left
((redBotX >= blueTopX) && (redTopY >= blueTopY) && (redBotX <= blueBotX) && (redTopY <= blueBotY)) || //top right
((redTopX >= blueTopX) && (redBotY >= blueTopY) && (redTopX <= blueBotX) && (redBotY <= blueBotY)) || //bottom left
((redBotX >= blueTopX) && (redBotY >= blueTopY) && (redBotX <= blueBotX) && (redBotY <= blueBotY)) //bottom right
) {
    //blue resides in red
}
```

Unfortunately, there are a couple of flaws in this logic. For example, what if red surrounds blue (like in situation 1)?

I thought this would be pretty easy but am having trouble coming up with a good way of covering all these situations.. can anyone help me out here?

Regards,
Tom

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A test that checks whether red *rectangle* resides completely *outside* the blue *rectangle* looks as follows

```
bool outside = 
  redBotX > blueTopX || redTopX < blueBotX || 
  redBotY > blueTopY || redTopY < blueBotY;
```

Now, the negative of that will tell you whether red rectangle intersects the blue rectangle

```
bool intersects =
  !(redBotX > blueTopX || redTopX < blueBotX || 
    redBotY > blueTopY || redTopY < blueBotY);
```

If you wish, you can apply the De Morgan rule and rewrite it as

```
bool intersects =
  redBotX <= blueTopX && redTopX >= blueBotX && 
  redBotY <= blueTopY && redTopY >= blueBotY;
```

Of course, the above tests assume that the coordinates are "normalized*, i.e.

```
assert(redBotX <= redTopX && redBotY <= redTopY);
assert(blueBotX <= blueTopX && blueBotY <= blueTopY);
```

Also, the comparisons might be strict or non-strict depending on whether you consider touching rectangles as intersecting or not.

**EDIT:** I see that you use a different convention for rectangle coordinates: `Top` is the lower coordinate and `Bot` is the higher one, i.e.

```
assert(redTopX <= redBotX && redTopY <= redBotY);
assert(blueTopX <= blueBotX && blueTopY <= blueBotY);
```

To handle this case you just need to swap the `Bot` and `Top` coordinates in all conditions. For example, the last one will now look as follows

```
bool intersects =
  redTopX <= blueBotX && redBotX >= blueTopX && 
  redTopY <= blueBotY && redBotY >= blueTopY;
```

Comment: I mistakenly accepted your answer before testing it, it doesn't actually work. redBotX <= blueTopX for example fails on most of the situations shown in the image I created.

Comment: (Since all the examples above need to return true, whether you look if red is inside blue or blue is inside red.)

Comment: if (RectA.X1 < RectB.X2 && RectA.X2 > RectB.X1 && RectA.Y1 < RectB.Y2 && RectA.Y2 > RectB.Y1) does seem to work.

Comment: @Tom: Everything in the answer works perfectly. The only thing is that in the answer I assumed different representation of a rectangle (I clearly stated it at the end - see the assertions). In my assumption `Bot` stands for minimum coordinate and `Top` stands for maximum. I.e. each rectangle is represented by its lower-left and upper-right corners. In your case it is lower-right and upper-left. If you insist on your representation, just update the comparisons (swap `...BotX` and `...TopX` everywhere). Although I'd say that your initial representation is rather... weird (why?).

Comment: Coordinates always go from lowest (top) to highest (bottom). Look at your screen resolution for example. Top means TopLeft X and Y while Bot means BottomRight X and Y.

Comment: @Tom: Well, it is a matter of choosing the axis direction and rectangle corners. I prefer mathematical directions: X goes to the right and Y goes to the up. But in any case, it is weird to the the word `Top` used for *lower* coordinate and the word `Bot` for the *higher* one. This might make some sense for `Y` axis (because of the screen), but for `X` axis it is just weird. In any case, all you need to do is to swap `Bot` and `Top` in my answer to get the right conditions for your specific case.

Comment: @Tom: Note also, that even in conventions with Y axis pointing down it is customary to use bottom-left (actual bottom) and top-right (actual top) corners to represent the rectangle. Bot again it is still totally up to you to choose the representation. Just rewrite the comparisons properly.

Comment: I see what you mean. I chose my coordinate system to reflect the coordinate system of the flash platform. When you increase y to a flash display object, it will move down. When you increase x, it will move right. This seems to be common practice from what I have seen, but it looks like it depends on what you're used work with. BotRight and TopLeft would probably be a better terminology for me to use though. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both squares are aligned, as you've indicated:

The squares intersect if all of the following hold:

1. The **left** side of Red is *left* of the **right** side of Blue.
2. The **right** side of Red is *right* of the **left** side of Blue.
3. The **top** of Red is *above* the **bottom** of Blue.
4. The **bottom** of Red is *below* the **top** of Blue.

(Convince yourself that this is true!)

Answer (score 1):

One formula for intersection of two rectangles would be

```
! ( (redTopX > blueBotX) || (blueTopX > redBotX) || (redTopY < blueBotY) || (blueTopY < redBotY))
```

You can use DeMorgan's Theorem to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (blueTopY < redBotY) return (0);
if (blueBotY > redTopY) return (0);
if (blueBotX < redTopX) return (0);
if (blueTopX > redBotX) return (0);
return (1); // there must clash
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for each blue corner:
  if corner is between all four red sides:
    return true
return false
```

Answer (score 1):

For higher-dimensional ranges or if you want to check a lot of ranges it might be worthwhile to store your ranges (e.g. their centers) in a [R tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and search for it for where the corners of your range are.