# Intersection algorithm

Tags: geometry, intersection, intersect

I have two objects in a CSharp project, which presents rectangles. Now I want to calculate if one object intersects another one. The objects cannot rotate.

I've got the following methods:

```
getX();
getY();
getWidth();
getHeight();
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other

Comment: Yeah, I found that out too... But that solution was waaay to complicated for me...

Comment: @YvanJANSSENS Because it was in pseudocode and provided thorough explanations instead of a mere C# code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this *is* technically a duplicate of that other question, I would propose a more elegant solution than what was posted there.

The way I would look at it would be from the perspective of the bounding box. If the bounding box is shorter than the sum of the heights AND skinnier than the sum of the widths, they must intersect:

```
// assume we have a class with a constructor like so...
class Rect
{
    ...
    void Rect(int top, int left, int bottom, int right) { ... }
    ...
}

...

private Rect GetBoundingRect(Rect r1, Rect r2)
{
    int left = min(r1.getX(), r2.getX());
    int right = max(r1.getX()+r1.getWidth(), r2.getX()+r2.getWidth());
    int top = min(r1.getY(), r2.getY());
    int bottom = max(r1.getY()+r1.getHeight(), r2.getY()+r2.getHeight());
    return new Rect( top, left, bottom, right );
}

private bool CheckIfIntersect(Rect r1, Rect r2)
{
    Rect bound = GetBoundingRect(r1,r2);
    return (bound.getWidth() < r1.getWidth() + r2.getWidth()) &&
           (bound.getHeight() < r1.getHeight() + r2.getHeight());
}
```