# Overlapping cubes

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to determine if two cubes overlap. I've read up on [overlapping rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other), but I'm not sure how to translate it into the third dimension.

My goal is to generate a number of randomly positioned and sized non-overlapping cubes.

These cubes are represented on a x,y,z Cartesian plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to modify [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other/306332#306332) to your purpose fairly easily.

Suppose that you have `CubeA` and `CubeB`.   Any one of 6 conditions guarantees that no overlap can exist:

```
Cond1.  If A's left face is to the right of the B's right face,
           -  then A is Totally to right Of B
              CubeA.X2 < CubeB.X1
Cond2.  If A's right face is to the left of the B's left face,
           -  then A is Totally to left Of B
              CubeB.X2 < CubeA.X1
Cond3.  If A's top face is below B's bottom face,
           -  then A is Totally below B
              CubeA.Z2 < CubeB.Z1
Cond4.  If A's bottom face is above B's top face,
           -  then A is Totally above B
              CubeB.Z2 < CubeA.Z1
Cond5.  If A's front face is behind B's back face,
           -  then A is Totally behind B
              CubeA.Y2 < CubeB.Y1
Cond6.  If A's left face is to the left of B's right face,
           -  then A is Totally to the right of B
              CubeB.Y2 < CubeA.Y1
```

So the condition for no overlap is:

```
Cond1 or Cond2 or Cond3 or Cond4 or Cond5 or Cond6
```

Therefore, a sufficient condition for Overlap is the opposite (De Morgan)

```
Not Cond1 AND Not Cond2 And Not Cond3 And Not Cond4 And Not Cond5 And Not Cond6
```

Comment: what do you mean by edges?, maybe faces?

Comment: Does your algorithm assume that the cubes are axis-aligned? Sry for bothering you^^

Comment: @Dave, it does.  As did the answers to the previous question.  If that assumption is wrong, the problem becomes more complex to solve.

Comment: Noone probably noticed, but there was an error in the post's Cond5. It reads "CubeA.Y1 < CubeB.Y2" but should read "CubeA.Y2 < CubeB.Y1"

Comment: Yeah, and stack overflow "edit review" brigade rejected my edit on the matter because it's "Addressed to the author". Yeah, good job. Let's leave a WRONG answer marked as correct one staying as it is!

Comment: @Istrebitel Thank you for pointing out the error, but you didn't quite have the right fix.  I fixed it properly.

Comment: @btilly are you sure? I am still seing cond5 being "CubeB.Y2 < CubeA.Y1" and cond6 being " CubeB.Y2 < CubeA.Y1", which is erroneous. It's the same condition twice, how can it be correct?

Comment: @Istrebitel I just fixed 6.

Comment: @btilly but you have just duplicated the condition 2, have you not? look!

Comment: this is still not fixed, ridiculous

Comment: what if cubeA contains cubeB or vice versa?

Comment: @shinxg Then none of the conditions will match. :-)

Comment: @Istrebitel I finally fixed it for you, thanks to https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/22 :)

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is wrong and very confusing. Here is what I have come up with.

**Determining overlap in the x plane**

```
    if (cubeA.maxX > cubeB.minX)
    if (cubeA.minX < cubeB.maxX)
```

**Determining overlap in the y plane**

```
    if (cubeA.maxY > cubeB.minY)
    if (cubeA.minY < cubeB.maxY)
```

**Determining overlap in the z plane**

```
    if (cubeA.maxZ > cubeB.minZ)
    if (cubeA.minZ < cubeB.maxZ)
```

if you AND all of these conditions together and the result is true, you know that the cubes intersect at some point.

Credit: https://silentmatt.com/rectangle-intersection/

Answer (score 3):

Cubes are made up of 6 rectangular (okay, square) faces.

Two cubes do not intersect if the following conditions are met.

- None of the faces of 2 cubes intersect.
- One cube does not completely contain the other.

The post you linked can be easily extended. Just add Z.

Comment: +1 easily implemented if you already have code that tests case 1

Comment: Just a side note...cube A completely contains cube B if cube A contains any vertex of cube B. You need only check one vertex of each cube for containment in the other cube; if the cube faces don't intersect, then either none of the vertices will be contained, or they all will be.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose (did not think much, maybe my condition is not enough) check if all the vertices of first cube are out of the second and inverse: all vertices of second are out of the first.

To check if the vertex is in the cube or not, transform it's coordinates to cube-related coordinate system (apply translation to the cube center and cube rotation). Then simply check each coord (x, y, z) is smaller then half a side

Comment: That condition is not enough, because all the vertices of each cube can be out of the other and yet they still intersect (for example, if cube A is a slightly-rotated copy of cube B, you should be able to arrange them so that the above condition is true but they still intersect).

Answer (score 0):

This is just the accepted answer rewritten with the correction. It tests to see if the two axis aligned cuboids have any segment of the X,Y, and Z axis in common, if they dont then it is impossible for them to have a collision. 
The function assumes there is a collision and performs the tests to check if there isnt.

```
Function func_Intersect(ByVal cuboid1_MinX As Double, ByVal cuboid1_MaxX As Double, ByVal cuboid1_MinY As Double, ByVal cuboid1_MaxY As Double, ByVal cuboid1_MinZ As Double, ByVal cuboid1_MaxZ As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MinX As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MaxX As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MinY As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MaxY As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MinZ As Double, ByVal cuboid2_MaxZ As Double) As Boolean
    func_Intersect = True
    If cuboid1_MaxX < cuboid2_MinX Then
        func_Intersect = False
    ElseIf cuboid2_MaxX < cuboid1_MinX Then
        func_Intersect = False
    ElseIf cuboid1_MaxY < cuboid2_MinY Then
        func_Intersect = False
    ElseIf cuboid2_MaxY < cuboid1_MinY Then
        func_Intersect = False
    ElseIf cuboid1_MaxZ < cuboid2_MinZ Then
        func_Intersect = False
    ElseIf cuboid2_MaxZ < cuboid1_MinZ Then
        func_Intersect = False
    End If
End Function
```