# Bounds intersection

Tags: algorithm, 2d, intersection, bounds, intersect

Given a `Bounds` structure like this:

```
struct Bounds {
  public double xMin;
  public double xMax;
  public double yMin;
  public double yMax;
}
```

I'm trying to find out how two `Bounds` *A* and *B* intersect. Possible results are:

- A and B do not intersect at all
- A and B are equal
- A fully contains B
- B fully contains A
- A and B intersect each other

My first and naive attempt at it, is to test how many points of A are in B and how many points of B are in A, but I need this test to be as fast as possible and there is probably a better way to do it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: totally 16 checks (ifs) should be simple and fast

Comment: Looks like a repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it in <strike>2D</strike> 1D first. It should be clear how to test two [x<sub>min</sub>, x<sub>max</sub>] objects for those five possible results. Then do the same for [y<sub>min</sub>, y<sub>max</sub>]. Then combine the two results:

- (no intersection)<sub>x</sub> + (anything)<sub>y</sub> = (no intersection)

  (equal)<sub>x</sub> + (something)<sub>y</sub> = (something)

  (A contains B)<sub>x</sub> + (A contains B)<sub>y</sub> = (A contains B)

  (A contains B)<sub>x</sub> + (A and B intersect)<sub>y</sub> = (A and B intersect)

  (A contains B)<sub>x</sub> + (B contains A)<sub>y</sub> = (A and B intersect)

(I think that covers it.)

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet: [facepalm] Thanks.