# How to make rect from the intersection of two?

Tags: python, pygame, rect, breakout

I'm working on a breakout clone and I've been trying to figure out how to get the intersection rect of two colliding rects so I can measure how deep the ball entered the block in both x and y axis and decide which component of the velocity I'll reverse.

I figured I could calculate the depth for each case like this:

[image: ball collision with blocks]

But if I had the intersection rect than I woudn't have to worry if the ball hits the block from the **left/right** or **top/bottom** (since I would be only reversing the x and y axis respectively), thus saving me a lot of typing.

I've looked on [Pygame's docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) but seems it doesn't have a function for that. How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: There are **lots** of duplicates of this question (e.g. [Rectangle intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675201/rectangle-intersection)).  Please use the search facility before posting a new question...

Comment: I don't know anything about Pygame, but I imagine it provides some way to get the coordinates/size of the rectangles?  In which case it should be relatively simple to translate any of the solutions presented in any of the [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rectangle+intersection)) to use Pygame...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have rectangles `r1` and `r2`, with `.left, .right, .top, and .bottom` edges, then

```
left = max(r1.left, r2.left);
right = min(r1.right, r2.right);
top = max(r1.top, r2.top);
bottom = min(r1.bottom, r2.bottom);
```

(with the usual convention that coordinates increase top to bottom and left to right). Finally, check that `left<right` and `top<bottom`, and compute the area:

```
Area = (right - left) * (top - bottom);
```

Alternatively, **you can use the `clip()` function**. From the docs you linked in your question:

> clip(Rect) -> Rect Returns a new rectangle that is cropped to be
>   completely inside the argument Rect. If the two rectangles do not
>   overlap to begin with, a Rect with 0 size is returned.

Comment: You are welcome. A bit ironic that I found the `clip()` answer in the docs you linked… sometimes you need another set of eyes. Bit of a strange name - but when I saw they had `union()` I figured it _had_ to be there, so I read more closely.

Comment: Yes! You know, I never ask questions before doing a google search and looking in the docs first. It bothers me when I can't solve problems like these on my own. I probably thought ``clip`` was like ``set_clip`` which has a completely different behavior. Maybe I should delete the question, you think?

Comment: It's up to you. If anyone else searches "rectangle intersection pygame" they find lots of hits to the boolean test - very few for the "area of overlap". Maybe this question will eventually make the list… You had trouble finding the answer - so might others.

Comment: Hmm. I don't this code is right. `top = max(r1.top, r2.top);` should be `min` and then we need to check if either `(right - left)` or `(top - bottom)` is negative (no intersection.) Also, is ending lines with a semicolon a pygame thing?

Comment: @BenB - actually with coordinates increasing top to bottom, it should have been `bottom = min(r1.top, r2.top);`. I added the check - good point. As for the semicolons: that's a hangover from writing mostly Matlab and C...

Comment: So probably we should get rid of the semicolons ;)  I would have gone to the standard graphing conventions of y increasing bottom to top. Is there a convention I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, [the convention is top-left = (0,0)](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/why-is-the-origin-in-computer-graphics-coordinates-at-the-top-left)