# How can I change the position of an element when it is touched by another element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to create a game just like this in javascript: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/. Except I'm not allowed to use the canvas element so the code I use doesn't seem to work. The problem I'm having is getting my mouse/food element to move to a random new position when the snake/slither element collides with the mouse/food element. I'm also generally not sure if my update() function is working and if it isn't I don't know why.

I've tried a lot of different ways to get the code to execute correctly; placing the update function in different places like window onload,in each arrow function, etc. I tried sourcing many other codes but all I can find is people who use the canvas element to create their game.

```js
var snake = null;
var slither = document.querySelector("#snake > .snake");
var mouse = document.querySelector("#food > .mouse");
var body = document.getElementById("grass");
x = body.width / 2;
y = body.height / 2;

function init() {
    snake = document.getElementById("snake");
    snake.style.position = 'relative';
    snake.style.left = '0px';
    snake.style.top = '0px';
}


function getKeyAndMove(e) {
    var key_code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    switch (key_code) {
        case 37: //left arrow key
            moveLeft();
            break;
        case 38: //Up arrow key
            moveUp();
            break;
        case 39: //right arrow key
            moveRight();
            break;
        case 40: //down arrow key
            moveDown();
            break;
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    snake.style.left = parseInt(snake.style.left) - 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveUp() {
    snake.style.top = parseInt(snake.style.top) - 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveRight() {
    snake.style.left = parseInt(snake.style.left) + 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveDown() {
    snake.style.top = parseInt(snake.style.top) + 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
window.onload = init;

var update = () => {
    if (
        mouse.x === slither.x || mouse.y === slither.y || mouse.y === slither.y && mouse.x === slither.x
    ) {
        mouse.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
        mouse.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
    }
};
```

```html
<body id="grass" onkeydown='getKeyAndMove(event)'>
        <div id="snake">
            <img class="snake" src="img/snek.png" alt="snake">
        </div>

        <div id="food">
            <img class="mouse" src="img/mouse.png" alt="mouse">
        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

I need answers only in JavaScript please because I haven't learned JQuery and all that yet.
I think there could be a problem with my x and y values but I don't know how to set the position of the mouse to move to relative to the window like they do in the canvas element examples. I'm just confused, please help.

Comment: You might consider adding the [`collision-detection`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/collision-detection/info) tag to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your collision detection needs works because you are currently only checking whether the left and top sides intersect, but there are many more combinations.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41201264/6860684) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974082/6860684) for more

I also changed the selector to move the div that holds the mouse the same way that you had defined for your snake. I also set it to be `position = 'relative';` so that it can move around. I added 'px' to the end of your random coord string

```js
var snake = null;
var food = null;
var slither = document.querySelector("#snake > .snake");
var mouse = document.querySelector("#food > .mouse");
var body = document.getElementById("grass");
x = body.width / 2;
y = body.height / 2;

function init() {
    snake = document.getElementById("snake");
    snake.style.position = 'relative';
    snake.style.left = '0px';
    snake.style.top = '0px';
    food = document.getElementById("food");
    food.style.position = 'relative';
}


function getKeyAndMove(e) {
    var key_code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    switch (key_code) {
        case 37: //left arrow key
            moveLeft();
            break;
        case 38: //Up arrow key
            moveUp();
            break;
        case 39: //right arrow key
            moveRight();
            break;
        case 40: //down arrow key
            moveDown();
            break;
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    snake.style.left = parseInt(snake.style.left) - 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveUp() {
    snake.style.top = parseInt(snake.style.top) - 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveRight() {
    snake.style.left = parseInt(snake.style.left) + 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
function moveDown() {
    snake.style.top = parseInt(snake.style.top) + 7 + 'px';
    update();
}
window.onload = init;

var update = () => {
    if (
        mouse.x === slither.x || mouse.y === slither.y || mouse.y === slither.y && mouse.x === slither.x
    ) {
        food.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1) + "px";
        food.style.right = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1) + "px";
    }
};
```

```html
<body id="grass" onkeydown='getKeyAndMove(event)'>
        <div id="snake">
            <img class="snake" src="img/snek.png" alt="snake">
        </div>

        <div id="food">
            <img class="mouse" src="img/mouse.png" alt="mouse">
        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for the details! The moveUp/Down/Left/Right functions are for the arrow keys and they work perfectly, what I'm stuck on is the function below 
```
var update = () => {
    if (
        mouse.x === slither.x || mouse.y === slither.y || mouse.y === slither.y && mouse.x === slither.x
    ) {
        mouse.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1) + 'px';
        mouse.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1) + 'px';
    }
};
```

I implemented your answer which placed the mouse as the top element so the snake moves around beneath him now.

Comment: I also changed the `update()` function. To have the snake on top, increase its z-index in css

Answer (score 1):

This code is untested but may get you started...

```js
function collisionCheck(elem1, elem2) {
    var elem1Bounds = elem1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elem2Bounds = elem2.getBoundingClientRect();

    var elem1Center = {
      x: elem1Bounds.left + (elem1Bounds.width / 2),
      y: elem1Bounds.top + (elem1Bounds.height / 2)
    }

    var elem2Center = {
      x: elem2Bounds.left + (elem2Bounds.width / 2),
      y: elem2Bounds.top + (elem2Bounds.height / 2)
    }

    // initialize if element 1 is within the viewport
    if (
        elem1Bounds.top >= 0 &&
        elem1Bounds.left >= 0 &&
        elem1Bounds.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        elem1Bounds.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    ) {

      // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628488/2116041
      var distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(elem1Bounds.x - elem2Bounds.x, 2) + 
        Math.pow(elem1Bounds.y - elem2Bounds.y, 2) 
      );

      if (distance > elem1Bounds.width && distance > elem1Bounds.height) {
        // no collision
        return false; 
      } else {
        // collision detected!
        return true; 
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi! Still nothing is changed for some reason. I took out the update function and replaced it with the collision function but am I just executing it wrong? Right now I have it check on each keydown of the arrow keys if it has collided with another element. But I think the above code is to check for the edges of the screen? But it still doesn't work so I don't know. Can I use the same strategy to make a collision for the snake and mouse?

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer I ended up with. I'm still tweaking some css stuff n all but this code does what I want it to :).
Also the positioning of the elements were the reason it wasn't staying in the window. I still have the rest of the code, this is just the important bits. Thanks for the help!

```
function init() {
    snake = document.getElementById("snake");
    snake.style.position = 'relative';
    snake.style.left = '0px';
    snake.style.top = '0px';
    food = document.getElementById("food");
    food.style.position = 'absolute';
}




function collisionCheck(slither, mouse) {
    var snakeBounds = slither.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseBounds = mouse.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (!((snakeBounds.top + snakeBounds.height) < mouseBounds.top ||
        snakeBounds.top > (mouseBounds.height + mouseBounds.top) ||
        (snakeBounds.left + snakeBounds.width) < mouseBounds.left ||
        snakeBounds.left > (mouseBounds.width + mouseBounds.left))) {

        food.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800) + 'px';  
        food.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 'px';
    }
}
```