# JS How to tell if two 2d boxes are touching using their vertex coordinates?

Tags: javascript, 2d

I have a 2d game in which I need to check collisions properly.
For example I need to check if one box touches another, when I have the cordinates of top left vertices of both and their side lengths.

```
// where side is side length
function touches(x1, y1, size1, x2, y2, size2){
     ...
}
```

I couldn't find any questions like this here, is there a way to create a function like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005136/how-do-i-see-if-two-rectangles-intersect-in-javascript-or-pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the two squares either touch or overlap, you can check if both the x and y coordinates are within the same range.

```
function touches(x1, y1, size1, x2, y2, size2){
    return (x1 >= x2 && x1 <= x2 + size2 || x2 >= x1 && x2 <= x1 + size1)
        && (y1 >= y2 && y1 <= y2 + size2 || y2 >= y1 && y2 <= y1 + size1);
}
```