# check whether if two squares are intersecting with each other

Tags: c++

I would like to check if two square are intersecting with each other. My idea is this

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       bool x = check line(i) of first square intersect with 
       line (j) of the second square
       if (x) return;
   }
```

any idea to optimize this code?

Comment: Are squares' lines are parallel to coordinate axes?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to loop through all coordinates to check if two squares intersect.

Here's a simple solution which will work as long as the squares are *not rotated*.

Say that you represent a square by its *top left corner* coordinate and its *side length*. Let `aX` and `aY` represent the coordinates and `aLen` the side length of square `A`, and vice versa for square `B`.

Then to check if square `B` intersects with square `A` evaluate this:

```
(aX < (bX + bLen) && (aX + aLen) > bX)
&& (aY < (bY - bLen) && (aY - aLen) > bY)
```

In other words, there are four possible scenarios and you check if either of square `B`'s corners are within the X-range of square `A` *and* that either of square `B`'s corners are within the Y-range of square `A`.

```
(Y)
 ^
 |             1:                        2:
 |       +--------+                   +--------+
 |       |        |                   |        |
 |       |   A +--|-----+       +-----+--+ A   |
 |       |     |  |     |       |     |  |     |
 |       +-----+--+ B   |       |   B +--+-----+
 |             |        |       |        |
 |             +--------+       +--------+
 |
 |             3:                        4:
 |       +--------+                   +--------+
 |       |        |                   |        |
 |       |   B +--|-----+       +-----+--+ B   |
 |       |     |  |     |       |     |  |     |
 |       +-----+--+ A   |       |   A +--+-----+
 |             |        |       |        |
 |             +--------+       +--------+
 |
 +-------------------------------------------------> (X)
```

For more info see this answer of a similar question: [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: The proposed formula seems too complicated, a much simpler exists: http://silentmatt.com/rectangle-intersection/ . See also the linked possible duplicate question.

Comment: @Ali, this is the same thing, just expressed in terms of corners and sizes

Comment: @JohanLundberg Please check the history: the answer has been edited in the meantime. The original formula was too complicated which is no longer visible.