# Creating a Windows 8 Explorer simulation - mouse selection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, mousemove

As a little practice I decided to recreate the Windows 8 Explorer file list panel, and all went well, until I wanted to add the mouse selection. It's basically the feature that allows you to select multiple files by dragging your mouse along the window, drawing a square, which should select all "files" that fall under it.

The only problem I have is that I can't seem to find a way to add the `selected` class to the elements under the selection

Here's the related code: *(full code available in a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/5Hzm4/1/))*

```
<ul class="files">
    <li>
        <span class="icon folder"></span>
        <span class="name">Folder</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
.selection {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #39F;
    background-color: rgba(51,153,255,.4);
    display: none;
}
```

```
$(function(){
    var $body = $(document.body);
    var selecting = false,
        $selectionDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('selection').appendTo($body),
        startX, startY;
    $body.on({
        mousedown: function(e){
            if (e.target === document.body){
                e.stopPropagation();

                startX = e.clientX;
                startY = e.clientY;
                selecting = true;

                $selectionDiv.show().css({top:startY+'px',left:startX+'px',width:'0px',height:'0px'});
            }
        },
        mousemove: function(e){
            if (selecting){
                var currentX = e.clientX,
                    currentY = e.clientY;

                var subX = currentX - startX,
                    subY = currentY - startY;

                if (subX < 0){
                    subX *= -1;
                    $selectionDiv.css('left',startX+(currentX-startX));
                }
                else $selectionDiv.css('left',startX+'px');

                if (subY < 0){
                    subY *= -1;
                    $selectionDiv.css('top',startY+(currentY-startY));
                }
                else $selectionDiv.css('top',startY+'px');

                $selectionDiv.css({
                    width: subX,
                    height: subY,
                });
            }
        }
    }).on('mouseup blur mouseleave',function(){
        if (selecting){
            $selectionDiv.hide();
            selecting = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to determine which elements are contained inside the selection box. Here's the code which seems to do the job (it's supposed to go into your `mousemove` event handler):

```
var topLeftX = Math.min(startX, currentX),
    topLeftY = Math.min(startY, currentY),
    bottomRightX = Math.max(startX, currentX),
    bottomRightY = Math.max(startY, currentY);

$('.files li').each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        width = $(this).outerWidth(),
        height = $(this).outerHeight();

    if (offset.left < bottomRightX
            && offset.left + width > topLeftX
            && offset.top < bottomRightY
            && offset.top + height > topLeftY) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

This code goes through all the elements of your file list and runs rectangle overlap test (the algorithm for which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306332/759064)) for the selection box and the list element. Usage of [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) makes sure that the border is also taken into consideration.

I also noticed that when you release the mouse your handler which resets the selection gets called:

```
$(window).click(function(){
    $('.files li').removeClass('selected');
})
```

As a possible solution, you can move this into your `mousedown` handler.

Here's JSFIddle which works for me in Chrome 35: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hzm4/2/

Comment: +1 for the explanation. They're becoming a rare sight these days