# Getting the overlapping area of two circles

Tags: android, geometry, collision-detection

I'm in a tremendous bind with a last minute request on a consulting project I'm working on.

Essentially here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a surfaceview that draws a series of randomly sized circles.  Each circle can have a radius from 50-100.

The x,y values are randomly generated along with a random radius

Each circle is created as an object representing that circle (x, y coord's and radius) and it is added to a list.

Once they are all created they are drawn.

The problem is I want to make sure none of these circles overlap.

I'm struggling a bit.  This seems like it's shouldn't be all that difficult but it is for me unfortunately.

Here's my code so far (I know it's not close...be kind):

```
    x = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * (mCanvasWidth - 200));
    y = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * (mCanvasHeight - 200));
    radius = 50 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
    color[0] = (float) (Math.random() * 360);
    color[1] = 1;
    color[2] = 1;

    String radVal = String.valueOf(radius);

    circle circ = new circle(x, y, radius, Color.HSVToColor(128, color), radVal);

    boolean addit = true;



    for (dot d : Dots) {
        int leftSide = d.get_x() - radius;
        int rightSide = d.get_x() + radius;

        int xBoundary = x + radius;
        int yBoundary = y + radius;

        int exist_xLeft = d.get_x() - d.get_radius();
        int exist_xRight = d.get_x() + d.get_radius();
        int exist_yTop = d.get_y() - d.get_radius();
        int exist_yBottom = d.get_y() + d.get_radius();

        if ((xBoundary > exist_xLeft) && (xBoundary < exist_xRight))
        {
            if (yBoundary > (exist_yTop) && (yBoundary < exist_yBottom)) {
                addit = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (addit)
        circles.add(mdot);

    if (circles.size() >= 5)
        running = false;
```

Then it iterates the circles list and draws them to the canvas.

Any suggestions on where I'm failing in the collision detection?

Comment: This answer gave me what I needed:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other

Comment: @markE Could you explain more? I was trying to test the expression assuming the following values: `cx1=0; cy1=0; r1=5; cx2=9; cy2=0; r2=5;`. In this case are not circles colliding?

Comment: @markE - Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried your solution and it does not work.  I still experience overlaps...albeit minor overlaps...there are still overlaps.

Comment: The answer you link to detects rectangle collisions rather than circle collisions. It provides approximate circle collisions, but will give false positives (it indicates circles colliding when they are not actually colliding). You can detect if 2 circles are colliding like this: Given centerpoints cx1,cy1 & cx2,cy2 and given radii r1 & r2, : areColliding=((cx2-cx1)*(cx2-cx1)+(cy2-cy1)*(cy2-cy1))<((r1+r2)*(r1+r2));

Comment: Works Perfectly!!!!!

I might also add that my name is Mark Edward (lastname)

From one MarkE to another...Thank you!

Comment: also markE if you'd like to set your response as the answer to the question I'm sure many would appreciate that equation.

I will gladly accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect if 2 circles are colliding like this:

Given:

- centerpoints cx1,cy1 & cx2,cy2
- and given radii r1 & r2,

Then you can determine if the 2 circles are colliding:

```
areColliding=((cx2-cx1)*(cx2-cx1)+(cy2-cy1)*(cy2-cy1))<((r1+r2)*(r1+r2));
```

Comment: In plain english, the expression means "If the distance between the two centerpoints are less than the sum of radii, then the circles are colliding."