# Identifying geometric relationship between two rectangles

Tags: c++, pathgeometry

I have gotten into programming recently, and was looking for some help.

For the algorithm that I'm trying to implement, there are two rectangle grids, with each cell containing an object. You can think of it as a 2D array of with an x-y coordinate assigned on its origin.

Given two integer number "m" and "n", I'm going to mark n cells in one grid and (m-n) cells in the other grid, so that **the marked area in one grid is the closest location for the marked area in the other grid** (vise versa).

For example, let's say grid A exists between coordinate (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and grid B exists between (a1, b1) and (a2, b2) (x1 < x2, y1 < y2, etc). 
If x2 < a1 and y2 < b1 (ie. grid B is on the top right side of grid A), the top right corner of grid A and bottom left corner of grid B will be marked.

I tried to design this using switch cases, but there seemed to be too many cases to be considered. If you know any better ways to do so, I would really appreciate if you can help me out.

If my question was too vague to understand, don't hesitate to point them out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but I think you mean a collision detection. If I'm right it'd look approximately like this, for a square :

```
(x + xYWidth >= a && x <= a + aBWidth) && (y + xYWidth >= b && y <= b + aBWidth)
```

For rectangles : [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your line. It's not a necessarily about collision detection, instead finding the two nearest areas in two rectangles. There can be an occurance that two rectangles have collided to each other, though.

Comment: I've found a solution :D took a long time, but there was a solution much simpler than this. Thanks though :)