# Apps Script getNamedRanges() returns "[Named Range]" instead of name of range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging

I'm pretty new to App Script, so this is a real head-scratcher for me.

With four named ranges on Sheet1 ("Range1","Range2","Range3","Range4")
`Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getNamedRanges());`

Returns `[NamedRange, NamedRange, NamedRange, NamedRange]`

The larger goal has been to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702296/google-sheets-scripts-get-named-range-from-active-cell) script working, to return the named range an active cell resides in.

Trying to get that working and debugging lead me to the above, making me wonder if the script isn't working due to how getNamedRanges is being returned?

Test Sheet file [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16oDm7ChSEGpCD6hid_TCuJmJWqmsYVqa_Fjxqk_XSf4/edit?usp=sharing).

Is the `[NamedRange]` result expected behavior or am I missing something to get the names of the ranges to return?

Thanks!

Comment: It's expected behavior.

Comment: [Your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behavior. When logging a  object of a class, the name of the class is usually logged in the `console`. `.getNamedRanges()` returns a array`[]` of `namedRange` objects.

```
console.log(
    SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    .getNamedRanges()[0]/*First namedRange*/
)//Expected: NamedRange Type: Object
```

Each  namedRange has many inbuilt functions, i.e., methods. A list of such methods is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range). One such method is `getName()`. You can use it to get the name of the `NamedRange` object:

```
console.log(
    SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    .getNamedRanges()[0]/*First namedRange*/
    .getName()/*First named range's name*/
)//Expected: "Range1" Type:string
```

You may use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all the names:

```
console.log(
    SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    .getNamedRanges()
    .map(namedRange => namedRange.getName())
)//Expected: ["Range1","Range2","Range3","Range4"] Type: Object(specifically a array of strings)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the clarification and pointing me in the right direction.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`getNamedRanges()` returns an array of NamedRanges.

```
let namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getNamedRanges());
namedRanges.forEach( namedRange => Logger.log(namedRange.getRange().getA1Notation()) );
```

will give a list of ranges in A1 notation such as

```
A1:B10
C2:Z100
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Display range name, sheet name and A1 Notation

```
function getSpreadsheetsNamedRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const nrA = ss.getNamedRanges().map(rg => [rg.getName(),rg.getRange().getSheet().getName(),rg.getRange().getA1Notation()])
  sh.clearContents();
  nrA.unshift(["Range Name","Sheet Name","A1 Notation"]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,nrA.length,nrA[0].length).setValues(nrA);
}
```