# Detect if two QML objects overlap

Tags: qml, qtquick2, overlap

Is there a clean way to detect when a `QML` object such as a `Rectangle` overlaps another? Here's an example with two `Rectangle`s colliding:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
       x: 50
       y: 100
       width: 300
       height: 300
       color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
       x: 30
       y: 100
       width: 300
       height: 300
       color: "green"
    }
}
```

Should I use `MouseArea`s?

Comment: Why don't you just compare x,y?

Comment: Because I am extremely stupid. God... (: I wasn't using x and y coordinates, but now that I typed them in stackoverflow in order to give an example, it became so obvious. Thanks.

Comment: :-) see answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other) question