# Find the frame name that a Userform.control resides in

Tags: vba

I have a Excel VBA Userform with two frames (Frame1 and Frame2) that I populate with a lot of Checkboxes depending on the amount of data when the form loads:

The interested code is:

```
Private Sub enterNewTextbox(number As Long, nameAdd As String, side As String)
    Dim boxTop As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim nameCB As String
    Dim checkBox As Control
    boxTop = 10 + (number * 18) - 18
    nameCB = side & number & "CB"
    If side = "Left" Then
        Set checkBox = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", nameCB)
    Else
        Set checkBox = Frame2.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", nameCB)
    End If
    With checkBox
        .Value = False
        .Top = boxTop
        .Left = 12
        .Width = 190
        .Name = nameCB
        .Caption = nameAdd
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I would like to loop through all the controls again and get all the controls that was added to the left frame - something like this:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
   If **{find the name of the frame that the Checkbox is in}** = "Frame1" Then
       'Be awesome here
   End If
End If
```

But when I look in the Properties of the control I don't find any field to query that shows me what frame it is in.

Comment: `ctrl.Parent.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Parent name.
`ctrl.Parent.Name`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, the `ctrl.Parent.Name` works quite ok on a `UserForm`, however if the controls are on a worksheet like this:

[image]

Or like ActiveX elements:

[image]

Then the `Parent` of the shape refers to the worksheet name and you have to solve the ***coordinate system*** problem:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
       Debug.Print shp.Name
       Debug.Print shp.Parent.Name
    Next shp
End Sub
```

returns:

```
Frame
Sheet1
Button 4
Sheet1
```

---

In programming schools, there are plenty of problems such as "***Define whether two squares in the coordinate system overlap each other***"

Every checkbox and every frame has the following 4 properties:

- Top
- Left
- Width
- Heigth

Knowing these, you could generate the Bottom and the Right positions:

- Bottom = Top + Height
- Right = Left + Width

Once knowing these, they overlap if the following condition is `TRUE`:

```
if (Frame.Left < Checkbox.Right && Frame.Right > Checkbox.Left &&
     Frame.Top > Checkbox.Bottom && Frame.Bottom < Checkbox.Top )
```

[Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)