# Find bounding set of rectangles

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I have an `std::vector` of `rectangle`'s. The class definition is quite simple:

```
class rectangle
{
public:
    rectangle();
    rectangle(int leftX, int topY, int width, int height);
    rectangle(const rectangle &other);

    int x() const;
    int y() const;

    int width() const;
    int height() const;

    // Returns the bounding rectangle of this rectangle and the given rectangle.
    rectangle united(const rectangle &r) const;
    rectangle intersected(const rectangle &r) const;

    // Returns true if rectangle intersects with given rectagle else false.
    bool intersects(const rectangle &r) const;
};
```

For each rectangle, I'd like to see if intersects another rectangle in the vector and then 'unite' them (find the bounding rectangle) *if* they intersect.

I'm quite keen to see if there is a way to use a function in `<algorithm>` to perform the search/combining on a range of rectangles. Can anyone advise on a possible solution? Looking for something that is concise without reinventing the wheel.

[EDIT:] I should mention that I have already implemented 'intersects()' and 'united'.

My end goal is to implement a function that works on my range of rectangles like so:

```
/// For each rectangle in the vector it test if it intersects with another and return the set of united rectangles. 
/// \param v A set of rectangles
/// \return A united set of rectangles.
std::vector<rectangle> test_intersect_and_unite(const std::vector<rectangle> &v)
{
    std::vector<rectangle> united;

    // ...

    return united;
}
```

I'd probably be handling less than 20 rectangles.

Comment: I see a desire expressed, but no actual question.  Or even requirements.  Have you tried anything?  Like, check each pair?  Did it work?  What went wrong if it didn't?

Comment: I had mentioned using 'algorithm' header file (with brackets) but it was not displayed because I hadn't escaped it - a bit clear now?.

You ask if I've tried anything - no. I can't see a solution from std::algorithm that fits my needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: @Sembei I don't think it's a duplicate because I've already implemented 'intersects' and 'united'. I'm looking for a function in STL to work on a range of rectangles.

Comment: So you already have an algorithm that checks if two rectangles overlap and creates the bounding box? What you look then is a way of comparing each pair of rectangles? Modify your question to ask exactly what you need and show what you have so far.

Comment: `For each rectangle, I'd like to see if intersects another rectangle in the vector and then 'unite' them (find the bounding rectangle) if they intersect.`, No you don't want that, you already have it, so you shouldn't ask for it in the question.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback. Can you suggest on how to rephrase the question? I'm attempting to outline my high-level goal. Yes you're right, I can determine if two rectangles intersect and 'unite' them, but I can't do that for a range of rectangles. Please understand, I'm not trying to be difficult.

Comment: Looping through the vector?

Comment: As far as I know there are no standard algorithm that do that... How many rectangles do you have to process? If you have only a few rectangles, then nested loops woulb be adequate. If you have many thousand, you probably need a more complex algorithm to get a reasonable performance.

Comment: Again, it is utterly unclear what you want to do; please try your best to implement it yourself.  There are a dozen or more decisions that I have no idea which you'd want in a solution (where does the result go?  Does this unioning process commute?  Is destructive ok?  How many elements we talking about?  If A B C pairwise intersect, do we get 1 2 or 3 output rectangles?), and a naive solution (together with why it isn't what you want) answers more than half of them.  I get it may be obvious to you, but we cannot read your mind.

Comment: Since you keep not posting the code you have so far I'm afraid we cannot really help you. What's `intersects`? a bool that tells you that the rectangle intersects another? What if it intersects more than one? What's `intersected`? The rectangle it intersects with? Shouldn't be the index where that rectangle is in your vector? What you should do is post a clear example of what you want (for example with only 3 or 4 rectangles) and show us the steps and results that you aim to obtain

Comment: You might get `find_if` to work, at least showing you what overlaps with what - but if everything overlaps with everything easle you may end up needing recursion or a bit more thought. You possibly want to avoid "unite"ing the elements of a vector as you iterate over it too - perhaps a new vector? See - there are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: I suggest you to manually write the algorithm you'd like to find in `<algorithm>`, chances are high that you will realize that a simple nested loop is sufficient (and replacing a loop with an algorithm not always improves readability)

Comment: A set of test cases, with your best explanation of what desirable properties each demonstrate, would be *very helpful*

Comment: Less than 20 rectangles? Just do a double loop to get each pair of rectangles (20*20=400 loops) then for each pair call your function `united` which returns the united rectangles and you are done.

Comment: From your title, I reckon that you want to find the **union** of a set of rectangles. In general, the union of two or more rectangles is not a rectangle, but can be represented by a set of rectangles, possibly smaller than the input. So, do you want to find such a smaller set, possibly the minimum such set? That's a non-trivial exercise in geometry, for which the standard library makes no provision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question seemed to have raised more confusion than answers. Perhaps I'm not very good at explaining myself. Nonetheless, this is my (naive) solution.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<template <typename, typename = std::allocator<rectangle>> class Container>
Container<rectangle> test_intersect_and_unite(const Container<rectangle> &v)
{
    Container<rectangle> vTemp{v};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vTemp.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < vTemp.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (i == j) { continue; }

            if (vTemp[i].intersects(vTemp[j]))
            {
                vTemp[i]  = vTemp[i].united(vTemp[j]);
                vTemp.erase(vTemp.begin() + j);
                if (j < i) { --i; }
                --j;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return vTemp;
}
```

Some simple unit tests:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class rectangle_utils_test : public testing::Test
{
public:

    rectangle_utils_test() = default;

    ~rectangle_utils_test() override = default;
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
TEST_F(rectangle_utils_test, test_intersect_and_unite)
{
    // TODO: This unit test makes some naive assumptions about ordering.
    // TODO: Test with negative values.

    {
        std::vector<rectangle> vArg = {{10, 10, 10, 10}, {15, 15, 10, 10}};

        std::vector<rectangle> v = test_intersect_and_unite(vArg);

        ASSERT_EQ(v.size(), 1);
        ASSERT_EQ(v[0], rectangle(10, 10, 15, 15));
    }

    {
        std::vector<rectangle> vArg = {{10, 10, 10, 10}, {21, 21, 10, 10}};

        std::vector<rectangle> v = test_intersect_and_unite(vArg);

        ASSERT_EQ(v.size(), 2);
        ASSERT_EQ(v[0], rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10));
        ASSERT_EQ(v[1], rectangle(21, 21, 10, 10));
    }

    {
        std::vector<rectangle> vArg = {{10, 10, 10, 10},
                                       {15, 15, 10, 10},
                                       {60, 60, 10, 10},
                                       {5,  5,  10, 10},
                                       {0,  0,  10, 10},
                                       {40, 40, 10, 10}};

        std::vector<rectangle> v = test_intersect_and_unite(vArg);

        ASSERT_EQ(v.size(), 3);
        ASSERT_EQ(v[0], rectangle(0, 0, 25, 25));
        ASSERT_EQ(v[1], rectangle(60, 60, 10, 10));
        ASSERT_EQ(v[2], rectangle(40, 40, 10, 10));
    }

    // Most interesting test case.
    {
        std::vector<rectangle> vArg = {{0,  0,  10, 10},
                                      {20, 20, 10, 10},
                                      {10, 10, 10, 10},
                                      {5,  5,  10, 10},
                                      {15, 15, 10, 10},
                                      {40, 40, 10, 10}};

        std::vector<rectangle> v = test_intersect_and_unite(vArg);

        ASSERT_EQ(v.size(), 2);
        ASSERT_EQ(v[0], rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
        ASSERT_EQ(v[1], rectangle(40, 40, 10, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the results here will be order dependent; it is easy to see that the results of a single `i=0` pass is.  Suppose A intersects B, and B intersects C.  If you have {A,B,C} in order then we get {A U B, C} then {A U B U C}.  If we have {A, C, B} in order then after the `i=0` pass we have {A U B, C}.  I haven't explicitly constructed it, but I'm pretty certain a long enough chain like A B C will result in different outputs depending on order.  Maybe not; possibly the n^2 passes prevent this.  But I'd be concerned and would want a proof.

Comment: The last test case aims to test what you describe albeit with a small set of data.  Nonetheless, for further peace of mind, it should be fairly easy to override `operator<` on the `rectangle` and use `std::next_permutation`.

Comment: my fear is a long chain might not collapse; no unit test can rule out it.  You would need a proof.