# SVG - Using checkIntersection() with transformed elements

Tags: javascript, svg, bounding-box

### TLDR;

I would like to use `svg.checkIntersection()` but am having difficulty getting/calculating the correct bounding box required by the function. What is the cleanest way to get the bounding box of a ***transformed*** SVG element ***in the initial coordinates of the SVG***?

---

I am trying to check for overlapping `text` elements in my SVG generated by code. The `text` elements are positioned at `(0, 0)` and maneuvred to the correct position using `transform` attribute, something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg0" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <text id="t0" transform="rotate(-30) translate(15 -5)">Text 0</text>
  <text id="t1" transform="rotate(-10) translate(15 -10)">Text 1</text>
  <!-- do they overlap? -->
</svg>
```

Note that the specific transforms used is not predeterminable.

So naturally one would try this:

```
const mySvg = document.querySelector("#svg0");
const text0 = mySvg.querySelector("#t0");
const text1 = mySvg.querySelector("#t1");
const isOverlap = mySvg.checkIntersection(text0, /* bounding box of text1 */);
```

The trouble is that there's no easy way to get this bounding box. [W3 definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__checkIntersection) states:

> The values are in the initial coordinate system for the current ‘svg’ element.

Therefore:

- `getBoundingClientRect()` is inappropriate because this SVG is intended to be a component in a `HTML DOM`, and `getBoundingClientRect()` would return values in the HTML coordinate system.
- `getBBox()` is not useful because it returns values in the element's local coordinate system, which is different than the SVG's initial coordinate due to the `transform` applied.
- `getCTM()` seems potentially useful, but manually applying the matrix to get the bounding box looks like a lot hand-written mathematics. I would like to avoid this if possible.

### So finally...

Given that there is no straight-forward built-in methods, what is the cleanest and/or easiest way to get an element's bounding box for use in `svg.checkIntersection()`?

Comment: Wrap the text in a group and get the bounding box for the group with getBBox()

Comment: @enxaneta thanks. This idea came up to me a few moments ago as well and it works for my use, since I am building the SVG component from scratch. I would still like to see a less clumsy solution though, because sometimes you really don't want to modify the DOM as that might break some other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution provided by OSUblake [here](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/13681-svg-gotchas/?do=findComment&comment=72060), combined with a simple rectangle intersection algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306332/5637701).

Basically, first compute a transform matrix from the object coordinate space to the SVG coordinate space:

```
const matrix = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(element.getScreenCTM());
```

Then apply the matrix to all four points of the element's bounding box and compute `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` from the minima and maxima.

```
const p = svg.createSVGPoint();

p.x = r.x;
p.y = r.y;
const pA = p.matrixTransform(matrix);

p.x = r.x + r.width;
p.y = r.y;
const pB = p.matrixTransform(matrix);

...
```

See original post for full implementation.

This did end up being essentially a big math function, something I did really want to avoid. But ultimately it does the job without requiring DOM changes. Combined with the simple intersection function, it did allow me to ditch `svg.checkIntersection()` too, which was giving weird results in the first place (tested on Chrome 83).