# Basic collision detection: need to know on which axis the collision occurred

Tags: c, collision-detection, game-engine

I have a rudimentary collision detection function that tells me if two bounding boxes are overlapping. This post describes it well:
[Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)
The code I use is simple and basically the same as the code from the post:

```
if (RectA.Left < RectB.Right && RectA.Right > RectB.Left &&
    RectA.Top > RectB.Bottom && RectA.Bottom < RectB.Top )
```

This works fine. My problem is, I need to know whether the collision occurred on the X or the Y-axis. This can be surmised from how much the boxes overlap on either axis:
[image]

As you can see, there's more overlap occurring on the Y-axis (8 pixels) than on the X-axis (only 1 pixel). I can use this to determine the boxes are colliding on the X-axis, however, I haven't been able to come up with a concise and efficient way to do so. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if the overlap is 1x1?  IMO, there is not enough information in the raw overlap area alone - I think it needs to be based on the movement of the objects instead.

Comment: Why don't you check more than one overlap? If in the next "frame" you have an X-overlap of still only 1 but a Y-overlap of e.g. 12, then the collision is obviously on the Y axis.

Comment: @0x5453 Good question. If it's a 1x1 area, that's OK as I don't think hitting a corner will look weird with the resulting code.

Comment: @Synthetix My point is that a 1x1 overlap could be formed by *any* box moving in *any* direction (including the easy-to-miss edge case where a box is "cutting across" the corner of the other box).  And 1x1 can be generalized to NxN.  You don't have enough information to resolve the collision - I guarantee there are cases where it *will* look weird.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm definitely open to other ways of doing this. If I need to use something like an object direction vector for a more accurate result, I can do that. I'm just trying to keep things as simple as possible. Can you suggest a fast way of checking the object trajectory?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the premise of your question is what's tripping you up: collision direction is a product of the *motion* of the objects, not the size and shape of the overlap.
You can't determine collision direction by analyzing a single frame.

As stated, your example does not provide enough information to determine the direction of collision.  For example, if Box 2 was a fast-moving body, it might result in your above scenario by "jumping over" Box 1 while moving from the *left*.  That might be an unlikely scenario in your game, but it emphasizes that you need to know how the objects are *moving* to determine your collision response.