# Non axis-aligned rectangle intersection

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will compute the intersection between 2 rectangles, which are not necessarily axis-aligned, and return the resulting intersection.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles) describes finding whether an intersection exists. I'd like to have the resulting shape of the intersection, if it exists.

My application of the algorithm will use one axis-aligned rectangle and one that is not necessarily axis-aligned, but a general algorithm would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is fully given here ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011267/area-of-rectangle-rectangle-intersection