# How to identify the boundary points of area overlapped between 2 rectangles in 2D?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, intersection

I'm looking to return the coordinates of the points bounding the area of overlap between 2 arbitrary rectangles in 2D. Whats the best way to approach this that would take care of all the special cases eg:

- Rectangles intersecting only on a single vertex ? (the program would have to return the lone vertex)
- Rectangles which share whole or part of a side ? (the program would have to return the endpoints of the common line segment)

To add to the complexity, it has to order the points in either clockwise/anticlockwise order. As such, I can use a convex hull algorithm to order them before reporting, but if there's an algorithm that can figure out the bounding points in order directly, that'll be the best !!

Any ideas of what avenues I should be looking at ? I'm not looking for code projects etc, only a general idea of a generic algorithm for which I don't have to keep a lot of 
`if "special case" then "do this"` kind of code.

EDIT: The rectangles are arbitrary - i.e. they may/may not be parallel to X/Y axis...

Comment: Numerous duplicates e.g. [Non axis-aligned rectangle intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089173/non-axis-aligned-rectangle-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the general convex polygon intersection method. Look up `intersect convex polygons rotating calipers`.

Comment: Yes, but they utilize the properties of rectangles - I was looking for one that would do so in order to minimize the implementation overhead...

Comment: A non-axis-oriented rectangle probably has no special easily exploitable properties. If you can rotate the scene such that one of the rectangles is axis-parallel, then there are easier methods thst clip against such a rectangle.

Comment: @n.m. That was my fallback plan -- picking a rectangle (that we could call the "base rectangle"), setting the origin to the base rectangle's lowest point ("lowest" meaning lowest y value) and then rotating both rectangles (via matrix multiplication [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix ]) so that the base rectangle exists in the upper right quadrant.  This would simplify things significantly, I'd imagine.  At the end of the calculation, you'd have to unrotate it, then move the origin back to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, we'll try this again...

Consider a union of the two, made up of areas defined by drawing a line from every vertex in ABCD (in black) to EFGH (in red):

[image]

The hard part here is coming up with all of the shapes defined by these lines (both the gray lines and the original lines coming from the ABCD and EFGH rectangles.)

Once you figure that out, create a linked list of these shapes, and assume every one of these shapes exists within the intersection.

**Step 1.** Translate & rotate everything so that ABCD has one vertex on 0,0 and its lines are parallel/perpendicular to the x and y axes.

**Step 1A.** Find the lowest y-value vertex in ABCD, and then subtract it from all other verts in the scene.  Let's assume for the purposes of demonstration that that vertex is C.  By subtracting C from every vertex in the scene, we will effectively move the origin (0,0) to C, making rotation around C easy.

```
for all shapes in linked list {
    for all vertices in shape {
        vertex -= C;
    }
}
```

**Step 1B.** Rotate everything about the origin by an angle equal to the angle between the C->B vector and the x-axis, so that B lands on the x-axis:

```
// see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
float rotRadians = atan2(B.x, B.y);  // assuming ABCD vertices are labelled clockwise

for all shapes in linked list {
    for all vertices in shape {
        rot(thisVert, rotRadians);
    }
}


// ...

// function declaration
void rot(theVertex, theta) {
    tempX = theVertex.x;
    tempY = theVertex.y;

    theVertex.x = cos(theta) * tempX + sin(theta) * tempY;
    theVertex.y = cos(theta) * tempY - sin(theta) * tempX;

}
```

If ABCD vertices were labelled clockwise, the ABCD vertices should now look like this:

```
A = ABCDx , ABCDy
B = ABCDx ,   0
C = 0     ,   0
D = 0     , ABCDy
```

(If they were not labeled clockwise, then the "lies within" check in Step 2 won't work, so make sure the vert used in the `atan2(...)` call is the vertex counterclockwise from the lowest vertex.)

**Step 2.** Now we can easily analyze whether or not a shape lies within the ABCD rectangle, e.g. `if (thisVert.x >= 0 && thisVert.y >= 0 && thisVert.x <= ABCDx && thisVert.y <= ABCDy)`.  Traverse the linked list of shapes, and check to make sure each vertex of each shape lies within ABCD.  If one vertex of a shape does not lie within ABCD, then that shape is not part of the ABCD/EFGH intersection.  Mark it as not part of the intersection and skip to the next shape.

**Step 3.** Undo the rotation from Step 1B, then undo the translation from Step 1A.

**Step 4.** Repeat Steps 1-3 with EFGH instead of ABCD, and you will have your intersection set.

---

If the only intersection between the two sets is a line, then the above will return nothing as an intersection.  If the intersection == NULL, then check for lines that intersect.

If the intersection is still NULL, then check for intersecting points.

Comment: I'm assuming for both rectangles, the naming starts from top-left vertex (once aligned with x-y axes) and then continues clockwise - making vertex B to be inside EFGH and E,F to be inside ABCD ?

Comment: Also, the crux of the computation lies in Step 0 (where all "shapes" have to be generated) and Step 2 (traversing linked link of shapes and making sure whether they intersect). These, along with rotation and transformation twice makes it quite lengthy to implement - I'm wondering if that has to be the case.

Comment: @shan23 It shouldn't matter where the naming starts from, so long as the lowest vertex is placed on the origin, and the vertex that is counterclockwise from it is used in the `atan2(...)` call.  These requirements ensure that the rectangle being aligned with the axes is placed within the upper-right quadrant.

Comment: Step 2, along with rotation and translation, should be very easy to implement, but I'd agree that creating all of the shapes initially might be difficult.  Perhaps if you made that a stackoverflow question of its own, someone might come up with an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably really rough but:

```
object rectangle { 

     pos  { x, y }              // top-left position
     size { height, width }     // rectangle-size
}


collision::check (rectangle rect) {

     // collision-detection logic 

     collision->order_coords(coords);   // order-coords clockwise;
     return collision_result_object;    // return collided vertices, ordered clockwise, or 0 if rect hit nothing
}

collision::order_rects (rectangle *rect, opt angle)  {

     return clockwise_rects; // returns rectangles ordered clockwise
}

collision::order_coords (coordinate *coord, opt angle) {

     return ordered_coords; // recieves coordinates and returns ordered clockwise
}

rectangle rects; // bunch of rectangles

ordered_rects = collision->order_rects (rects); // order rects starting at 12PM

loop {    

       foreach ordered_rects as i {

           if (collision->check(i)) {

           array_of_collision_result_objects[i] = collision->check(i);      // start checking rects starting at 12PM, if collision found, return ordered vertexes
           }
       }

}
```

Comment: Missed the basic point - the rectangles are non-axis aligned, so top-left and height, width don't give you the rest of the points !!

Answer (score 0):

Find all the intersections of segments of rectangles. The result consists of some of them and some of initial vertices. To find them just check for every point it lies in both rectangles. Remove unnecessary points (if there are 3 or more on one line). The result is convex and no point you get is strictly inside it, so (if there are at least 3 of them) sort points from some inner point by angle and enjoy the result.

Comment: Nope - you'll be missing the case when one rectangle is completely inside other, so the overlapping area consists of the smaller rectangle itself. Observe the wording in the question - it doesn't say intersecting points only, but the boundary points of the overlapping area.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction. By initial vertices I meant the vertices of rectangles themselves. In such case we'll get no intersection points, check that 4 points of the inner rectangle lie in both and then sort them by angle.

Comment: Also your answer is identical to my one. To check if the point P is inside some convex polygon you should just check that for every edge AB the vector products AB \times AP have the same sign (unless 0). Here edges should go in one direction.

Comment: IMO, your answer wasn't very clearly stated, especially the last line - that's why I wanted to spell it out clearly to see if anyone could see a flaw in my logic. Its not very ethical to accept my own answer, so I'll let it be - but that's what I'll be implementing now.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a reasonable method that should cover all possible cases:

All we need is basically 3 steps :

Step 1:

```
for each side Si of R1
    for each side Sj of R2
           Check if Si and Sj intersect. If they do, push the point in results array
           (This also has to take care of the case in case Si and Sj overlap, which is 
           basically checking if they  have the same equation or not - if so, push in 
           the points of overlap. This also takes care of the case where a vertex of 
           R2 lies on Si).
    next
next
```

Step 2:

```
for each vertex Vi of R1
   Check if Vi lies inside R2, If so, push it in the results array.
next
```

Step 3:

```
for each vertex Vi of R2
   Check if Vi lies inside R1, If so, push it in the results array.
next
```

Now, order the results array, and return

For step 2 & 3 (how to find if a point lies inside a rectangle) - I'd use [this excellent article](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122124153/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54386.html)  (the last algorithm stated there).