# Java Implementation of Rectangle Intersection Algorithm..?

Tags: java, intersection

I am interested in this algorithm: [Algorithm to detect intersection of two rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles)

but unable to implement it myself lacking even basic mathematical skills. I think I could understand it better once I can read the code. Does somebody perhaps have already an implementation or can quickly write one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If you're using Java, all
>   implementations of the Shape interface
>   have an intersects method that take a
>   rectangle.

from [Algorithm to detect intersection of two rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles/115476#115476)

[Java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#intersects(double,%20double,%20double,%20double))