# Difference between intersection algorithm and Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle r)

Tags: java, collision-detection

Someone on a forum I go to said I shouldn't use `Rectangle.intersects` for my collision detection, and I should use this algorithm instead:

```
boolean rectangleIntersects(float rect1x, float rect1y, float rect1w, 
                            float rect1h, float rect2x, float rect2y, 
                            float rect2w, float rect2h)
{
    return (rect1x + rect1w >= rect2x &&
            rect1y + rect1h >= rect2y &&
            rect1x <= rect2x + rect2w &&
            rect1y <= rect2y + rect2h);
}
```

But isn't the `Rectangle.intersects` algorithm different, and better than this?

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles) helpful in developing a better intersection algorithm.

Comment: Did they give a reason for the suggestion?

Comment: You had duplicated parameter names in your method signature, I've edited with my assumption as to what you intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Rectangle.intersects` is basically the same](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.java#Rectangle2D.intersects%28double%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%29) except that your algorithm uses `float` instead of `double` and includes equality conditions for the bounds.