# Check if a position is free in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I managed to create an array of Picture Boxes.

```
private: static array<System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^>^ pictures = (gcnew array<System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^>(64));
```

Now, I would like to spawn a Picture Box if a certain position (coordX,coordY) is free. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need a rectangle intersect algorithm then you do sometings like this

```
var desiredX = ?;
var desiredY = ?;
var desiredW = ?;
var desiredH = ?;
var intersect = false;

foreach(var picture in pictures){
   if(picture intersect(desiredX, desiredY, desiredW, desiredH)){
     intersect = true;
     break;
   }
}

if(!intersect){
  //add new picture here
  pictures.add(newPicture);
}
```

[For intersect algoritm you can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390333/two-rectangles-intersection)

Comment: I suppose I can convert the Foreach loop into a C++ For loop.

Comment: @KamiV You can use the C++/CLI [`for each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx). It's one of the [spaced keywords](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hsutter/2003/11/23/ccli-keywords-under-the-hood/).