# Check if two rectangles overlap or the edges touch

Tags: c++, geometry, cartography

I get geo coords in lon and lat, like NorthWest and SouthEast lon/lat. So, when I got them I translating into metric system. So here I get my first rectangle with north_west and south_east coords, then I have bounding-rectangle in same metric system with north, south, west and east coords. And I needed check this two rect on intersection within edges touch, what I wrote:

```
bool filter(TilePosition const& tile_position) const noexcept override 
{
    MetricBoundingBox tile_bounds{tile_position};

    bool cond1 = (tile_bounds.north <= south_east_.lon);
    bool cond2 = (tile_bounds.south >= north_west_.lon);
    bool cond3 = (tile_bounds.west <= south_east_.lat);
    bool cond4 = (tile_bounds.east >= north_west_.lat);

    return cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
}
```

And I'm not sure if I did it right? My requirement is if the borders of the second rect intersect with the borders of the first rect, then the second must be left. Else, filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: Also related (and language agnostic): [Two Rectangles intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13390333/2602718)

Comment: @scohe001 I see that question but I'm needed to check is my solution is right? Realy hard to test it for me.

Comment: You check if first rectangle is within bounding one, this maybe correct or not depends on requirement. Your condition will return false if two rectangles overlap partially

Comment: Also, it's a nice habit to write some tests to ensure that your code is correct. It's the easiest way to determine this, besides proving analytically the correctness of your algorithm. Relatively to this problem, you can just check few edge cases and simple overlapping.

Comment: @Slava thx for a answer, can u tell me how to fix dat? My requirement is if the borders of the second rect intersect with the borders of the first rect, then the second must be left. Else, filter.

Comment: @KirillKorolev yea, I'm trying but it's looks like my solution is wrong. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You can use solution in link provided by @scohe001

Comment: I'm quite sure you did it wrong, unless you have intentionally reversed the meanings of latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Slava I understand but I had another coords system and I actually not sure if I compare them right, is I rightly introduce x, y with south, north, east, west?

Comment: @BenVoigt can you tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: @Azazel-San: You are comparing east-west of one rectangle with north-south of the other.  This makes no sense.

Comment: @scohe001: Not quite a duplicate, because this question is in cylindrical coordinates (and not actually rectangles at all...)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct.

Besides confusing the meaning of latitude and longitude, you have a fundamental problem that algorithms designed for cartesian coordinate space do not work in cylindrical coordinates, because longitude is periodic.  Things may look ok for rectangles near the meridian, but when you start testing near the wrap point (+/- 180 degrees longitude) this method will fail.

One simple fix is to break each rectangle that crosses the wrap point into two that do not cross.