# How to find intersect between two ImageView when drag and drop?

Tags: android, imageview

I have  two `ImageView`

1. One is fixed at a position
2. On Second I need to apply drag an drop functionality.

What I need:

Drag second `ImageView` to the another `ImageView` and when they intersect than I need to call a method.

**EDIT 1:**

**Intersect b/w two imageView is `DONE` but on the drag n drop it's not happening.**

**Edit 2 :**

**How can I achieve this thing on `Drag and drop`?**

Answer (score 10):

I assume that you need this functionality for Android.
The easiest way is to use intersects method found in Rect class. [Link to documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

```
import android.graphics.Rect;

...

Rect rc1 = new Rect();
imageView1.getDrawingRect(rc1);
Rect rc2 = new Rect();
imageView2.getDrawingRect(rc2);
if (Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2)) {
  // intersection is detected
  // here is your method call
}
```

*EDIT added missing right bracket

Comment: doesn't get the intersect

Comment: see the EDIT 1 :else part is printed

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not help in assisting you. Since I'm pretty confident that Rect.intersects works as expected - you need to troubleshoot your code. I would start with printing myViewRect and otherViewRect1 to output log to validate rectangles data.

Comment: in above edit two imageView is in layout both overlap each other and this code. Did I mistake somewhere

Answer (score 5):

This is my Solution that works

```
private boolean isViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {

        final int[] location = new int[2];

        firstView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        Rect rect1 = new Rect(location[0], location[1],location[0] + firstView.getWidth(), location[1] + firstView.getHeight());

        secondView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        Rect rect2 = new Rect(location[0], location[1],location[0] + secondView.getWidth(), location[1] + secondView.getHeight());

        return rect1.intersect(rect2);
//        return  (rect1.contains(rect2)) || (rect2.contains(rect1));
    }
```

call the above function in

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

if(isViewOverlapping(view,child))
                                {Toast.makeText(this,"Overlapping with "+child.getTag() or text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
 @override 
 onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focus)
```

and put your code in there cz onCreate()/onStart() - this will not work

Comment: what about the Drag and drop functionality

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have the drag and drop functionality created for the second `ImageView`?

If so, all you need to do is call [getLeft(), getRight(), so on](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Position) to find the position of your second view after the drag (or on a Handler every few increments while it's being dragged), then this becomes a simple rectangle intersection problem, which [already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles/115476).

Comment: can You  please check the EDIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I also had this problem and fixed it with the following code. The solution for Action drop is answered here, so I don´t post it again. But if You want to detect it **WHILE DRAGGING** , you have to do that stuff inside `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION`.

1. get x y of current drag event:

   ```
   int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
   int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
   ```
2. now calculate the size of the rect. For that (in my case) if have to divide the size of the view because the drag position was in the center of it and then calculate the top/left/right/bottom:

   ```
   int left = (int) (x_cord - halfViewSize);
   int top = (int) (y_cord - halfViewSize);
   int right = (int) (x_cord + halfVaieSize);
   int bottom = (int) (y_cord + halfViewSize);
   ```

I casted the value because in my case halfViewSize was a `float`. If you have an `integer`, you don´t need to cast.

3. Now you can build a rect with these values:

   ```
   Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
   ```
4. create a method which checks if the rect intersects with a rect of your childViews:

   ```
   private boolean collideWithOthers(Rect rect) {

       int count = yourParentLayout.getChildCount();

       boolean intersects = false;
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

           ImageView squareInside = (ImageView) yourParentLayout.getChildAt(i);

           Rect rectInside = squareInside.getCollisionRect();
           if (rectInside.intersect(rect)) {
               Log.d("TAG", "ATTENTION INTERSECT!!!");
               intersects = true;
               break;//stop the loop because an intersection is detected

           }

       }

       return intersects;
   }
   ```

Now you can do this stuff inside  `ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION`:

```
    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();

    int left = (int) (x_cord - halfViewSize);
    int top = (int) (y_cord - halfViewSize);
    int right = (int) (x_cord + halfVaieSize);
    int bottom = (int) (y_cord + halfViewSize);

    Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    boolean collide = collideWithOthers(rect);
```

I hope this will fit to your needs, if not, maybe it´s helpful for others.