# Check collision between rectangles AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

What is quick way to check collision between 2 rectangles then you have rectangle coordinates like:

Red rectangle: A1(x1, y1), B1(x2, y2).

Blue rectangle: A2(x3, y3), B2(x4, y4).

[image]

Comment: This post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hitTestObject is your hero.

```
// Create Box1
var box1:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
box1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
box1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, x2-x1, y2-y1);
box1.graphics.endFill();
box1.x = x1;
box1.y = y1;
addChild(box1);

// Create Box2
var box2:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
box2.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
box2.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, x4-x3, y4-y3);
box2.graphics.endFill();
box2.x = x3;
box2.y = y3;
addChild(box2);


//Now test if collide
var _collide:Boolean = box1.hitTestObject(box2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you check the Rectangle class [Link to AS3 Doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html)?

> intersection(toIntersect:Rectangle):Rectangle
>
> If the Rectangle object specified in the toIntersect parameter intersects with this Rectangle object, returns the area of intersection as a Rectangle object.
>
> intersects(toIntersect:Rectangle):Boolean
>
> Determines whether the object specified in the toIntersect parameter intersects with this Rectangle object.