# Collision detection for rotating images

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision-detection

I want to be able to tell when 2 images collide (not just their frames). But here is the catch: the images are rotating.
So I know how to find whether a pixel in an image is transparent or not but that wont help in this scenario because it will only find the location in the frame relative to a non-rotated image.
Also I have gone as far as trying hit boxes but even those wont work because I can't find a way to detect the collision of UIViews that are contained in different subviews.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you added imageView1 and imageView2 to some mainView with different frames and you rotate them.Now you want to know whether they intersect or not. (like any part of imageView1 overlaps with view2 right?

Comment: yes, exactly any suggestions?

Comment: i had answered a similar question. feel free to check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758271/detecting-collisions-between-rotated-uiviews/21802849#21802849  Hope it helps

Comment: You will notice that UIKit Dynamics makes no attempt to do this - it measures collisions at the frame, not the interior image. There is probably a good reason for this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would go about checking for pixel collision on a rotated image. That would be hard. I think you would have to render the rotated image into a context, then fetch pixels from the context to check for transparency. That would be dreadfully slow.

I would suggest a different approach. Come up with a path that maps the bounds of your irregular image. You could then use CGPathContainsPoint to check to see if a set of points is contained in the path (That method takes a transform, which you would use to describe the rotation of your image's path.)

Even then though you're going to have performance problems, since you would have to call that method for a large number of points from the other image to determine if they intersect.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a simple strategy to solve that, based on looking for rectangles intersections.

The key for that is to create a simplified representation of your images with a set of rectangles laid out properly as bounding boxes of the different part of you image (like you would build your image with legos). For better performance use a small set of rectangles (a few big legos), for better precision use a biggest number of rectangles to precisely follow the image outline.

Your problem becomes equivalent to finding an intersection between rectangles. Or to be more precise to find wether at least one vertex of the rectangles of object A is inside at least one rectangle of object B (CGRectContainsPoint) or if rect intersects (CGRectIntersectsRect).

If you prefer the points lookup, you should define your rectangles by their 4 vertices then it is easy when you rotate your image to apply the same affine transform (use CGPointApplyAffineTransform) to your rectangle vertices to have the coordinates of your points after rotation. But of course you can lookup for frame intersections and represent you rectangle using the standard CGRect structure.

You could also use a CGPath (as explained in another answer below) instead of a set of rectangles and look for any vertex inside other path using CGPathContainsPoint. That would give the same result actually but probably the rectangles approach is faster in many cases.

The only trick is to take one of the objects as a reference axis. Imagine you are on object A and you only see B moving around you. Then if you have to rotate A you need to make an axis transform to always have B transform relatively to A and not to the screen or any other reference. If your transforms are only rotation around the object centre then rotating A by n radians is equivalent to rotating B by -n radians.

Then just loop through your vertices defining object A and find if one is inside a rectangle of object A.

You will probably need to investigate a bit to achieve that but at least you have some clues on how to solve that.