# Detect intersection between two ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, intersect, rect

I have two ImageViews and I want to detect the intersection between the two images. So I decided to find a solution online, I'm using getDrawingRect to draw a rectangle, wrapping with the ImageView. However, I have a problem when I run the codes. Both imageViews don't get intersect but Rect.Intersect return true. Always true, no matter they got intersect or not.
Below is my codes.

**Intersection between two images**

```
Rect rc1 = new Rect();
rc1.left = arrow.getLeft();
rc1.top = arrow.getTop();
rc1.bottom = arrow.getBottom();
rc1.right = arrow.getRight();
arrow.getDrawingRect(rc1);

Rect rc2 = new Rect();
rc2.left = view.getLeft();
rc2.top = view.getTop();
rc2.bottom = view.getBottom();
rc2.right = view.getRight();
view.getDrawingRect(rc2);

if (Rect.intersects(rc1,rc2))
{//intersect!}
else{//not intersect}
```

**First ImageView**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/needle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerFrame"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/arrow_top" />
```

**Second ImageView**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/letter_a"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/needle"
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/needle"
android:scaleType="matrix"
android:src="@drawable/letter_a" />
```

Comment: Maybe it is a duplicated question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is in incorrect function used to obtain `ImageView` rectangle on the screen. Refer to [getDrawingRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29) docs:

```
Return the visible drawing bounds of your view. Fills in the output rectangle with the values from getScrollX(), getScrollY(), getWidth(), and getHeight().
```

So, for both `ImageView` it returns almost the same rectangles, because it returns 'internal' rect.

To obtain rectangle on the screen, you need to use [getLocationInWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int[]%29), [getLocationOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int[]%29) or [getLocalVisibleRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocalVisibleRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29). Then, your code might look the following way (using `getLocalVisibleRect()`):

```
// Location holder
final int[] loc = new int[2];

mArrowImage.getLocationInWindow(loc);
final Rect rc1 = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1],
        loc[0] + mArrowImage.getWidth(), loc[1] + mArrowImage.getHeight());

mLetterImage.getLocationInWindow(loc);
final Rect rc2 = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1],
        loc[0] + mLetterImage.getWidth(), loc[1] + mLetterImage.getHeight());

if (Rect.intersects(rc1,rc2)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Intersected");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Intersected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "NOT Intersected");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Not Intersected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```