# If two rectangles intersection is zero in matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d

Knowing center of the two rectangles and their angle by x axis (horizontal axis), how can one recognize if their intersection is zero or not in Matlab? Any answers containing this information is highly appreciated. Width and length of rectangles are also known

Comment: This is a math question not a MATLAB question.

Comment: But I want to solve it by matlab @AnderBiguri Do you know what can I do?

Comment: First figure out the math problem, then come here, describe it and tell us what are you having the programming problems with it. I write my maths in paper, but I do not ask a paper company for solutions because the fact that I am doing it in paper doesn't mean it is a paper problem. Replace paper by MATLAB.

Comment: You are right. THhank you for your help @AnderBiguri

Comment: Could anyone answer this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a maths problem, not a programming problem

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a programming problem if you want to solve it numerically. For exact solutions, you could use geometrical equations.

---

The first problem: defining a rectangle's corners from its width, height and centre:

```
C1 = [0, 0];    % Centre of rectangle 1 (x,y)
C2 = [1, 1];    % Centre of rectangle 2 (x,y)
W1 = 5; W2 = 3; % Widths of rectangles 1 and 2
H1 = 2; H2 = 3; % Heights of rectangles 1 and 2
% Define the corner points of the rectangles using the above
R1 = [C1(1) + [W1; W1; -W1; -W1]/2, C1(2) + [H1; -H1; -H1; H1]/2];
R2 = [C2(1) + [W2; W2; -W2; -W2]/2, C2(2) + [H2; -H2; -H2; H2]/2];
```

Next problem is to create many points which represent the edges of the rectangles. You could instead generate many points *within* the rectangles if you wanted to look at intersecting areas.

```
n = 1000;       % Define some number of points to use
% Use interp1 to interpolate around the rectangles
R1points = interp1(1:5, [R1; R1(1,:)], linspace(1,5,n));
R2points = interp1(1:5, [R2; R2(1,:)], linspace(1,5,n));
```

Then rotate the rectangles:

```
a1 = deg2rad(0); a2 = deg2rad(30); % angles of rotation for rectangle 1 and 2 respectively
R1rotated(:,1) = (R1points(:,1)-C1(1))*cos(a1) - (R1points(:,2)-C1(2))*sin(a1) + C1(1);
R1rotated(:,2) = (R1points(:,1)-C1(1))*sin(a1) + (R1points(:,2)-C1(2))*cos(a1) + C1(2);
R2rotated(:,1) = (R2points(:,1)-C2(1))*cos(a2) - (R2points(:,2)-C2(2))*sin(a2) + C2(1);
R2rotated(:,2) = (R2points(:,1)-C2(1))*sin(a2) + (R2points(:,2)-C2(2))*cos(a2) + C2(2);
```

Finally, check intersection with [`inpolygon`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html):

```
in1 = inpolygon(R1rotated(:,1), R1rotated(:,2), R2rotated(:,1), R2rotated(:,2));
in2 = inpolygon(R2rotated(:,1), R2rotated(:,2), R1rotated(:,1), R1rotated(:,2));
```

**If `nnz(in1)>0` or `nnz(in2)>0` then you have an intersection!** Visualise it using scatter:

```
hold on
scatter(R2rotated(:,1),   R2rotated(:,2),   '.b')
scatter(R2rotated(in2,1), R2rotated(in2,2), 'xc')
scatter(R1rotated(:,1),   R1rotated(:,2),   '.r')
scatter(R1rotated(in1,1), R1rotated(in1,2), 'xg')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: A really nice answer, but is a there simpler way to do that without rotation?

Comment: You say in the question that you wanted rotation? You can leave out the rotation lines or set `a1` and `a2` to 0 if you want to use rectangles which are orthogonal to the axes

Comment: There are simpler ways even with rotation.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer @Jed if you can improve on this, this is just the first way which came to my mind

Comment: I posted my matlab implementation here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210241/5535270

Comment: How about this method? Posted the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles/44216173#44216173